# Limit of a complex function - Output=input

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to compute the following limit:

```
Limit[ (E^(I t w)) /(2 (-I + 1)), t -> Infinity]
```

but Mathematica does not compute it. The above limit does not exist, thus I expect that Mathematica gives to me an answer (output) different from the question (input).
How can I get the right answer?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: `Limit[ComplexExpand[(E^(I t w))/(2 (-I+1))], t->Infinity]` says this is `1/4 Limit[ Cos[t w]-Sin[t w]+I (Cos[t w]+Sin[t w]),  t->Infinity]]` and clearly neither the real nor the complex part of that has a limit

Comment: What is the result you are expecting?

Comment: Hello @DanielLichtblau, I expect the result "impossible" or something like that (e.g. the limit does not exist).

Comment: Sometimes `Limit` returns `Indeterminate` but offhand I do not know what cases give that result.

Answer (score 3):

The result depends on $w$:

```
Limit[(E^(I t w))/(2 (-I + 1)), t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> w > 0]
```

> Indeterminate

```
Limit[(E^(I t w))/(2 (-I + 1)), t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> Im[w] > 0]
```

> 0

```
Limit[(E^(I t w))/(2 (-I + 1)), t -> Infinity,Assumptions -> Im[w] < 0]
```

> ComplexInfinity

Comment: Hello @user64494, I copied your first statement and I got: 1/4 (I E^(2 I Interval[{0, \[Pi]}]) + E^(2 I Interval[{0, \[Pi]}])). What does E^Interval mean?

Comment: @Gennaro Arguzzi: This means the set of the limits of the subsequences of (E^(I t w))/(2 (-I + 1)) over all the subsequences t->Infinity. My result is obtained in version 11.3.

Comment: I'm using version 11.2...maybe the result description in 11.3 is better.

Comment: Yes, but this does not use Direction->Complexes. Without it it is not a true Complex limit (i.e. in all directions). It cannot solve any of your examples with that option.